# Moving active rigidbodies with a passive one

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

is there any way to make one or more active rigidbodies with a single passive one? (Without animating the active ones) Hopefully this should explain what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Comment: If the top body is the active, just increase friction on both bodies, under "surface response" in physics.

Comment: Oh, and don't make it passive, make it active but "animated".

Comment: @Nathan Why make it _Active_? That's not necessary to interact with the other active object... but enabling _Animated_ is crucial.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh, I guess you're right-- I'm just not in the habit of using "passive" for anything that's not static.

Comment: Edit: I forgot to read everything and was going to say it did need to be active, but yeah, it does just need to be animated. Thanks for the help!